# Color changing orbs dropped by enemies in The Legend of Zelda Wind Waker HD

Tags: zelda-wind-waker

Me and my brother have recently been getting really into The Legend of Zelda Wind Waker HD for the Wii U, and my brother was recently wondering about the orbs that some of the higher ranking enemies drop. They shift through different colors and the color seems to affect the rewards spilled when you hit it. He was wondering what are the pros for hitting one color over another.

Comment: Red gives you health, I think.  Green gives you magic.  I don't remember any of the others, but I think one gives you money.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The color of the orb affects the distribution of its content. Red favors health, green favors magic pots, and yellow favors rupees and spoils. Note that spoils will only drop if they haven't already been stolen with the grappling hook.

You will still have a chance to receive other pick-ups, but the color weights the pick-up distributions towards its favored item.

Comment: There is also a purple color though... What is that one for?

Comment: Ah, in that case yellow would be rupees and purple would be spoils.

Comment: Can you back this up with a source? Your answer doesn't seem to be true as far as I've seen.

Answer (score 7):

The color of the orb **does not** affect the distribution of its content.

This can be trivially verified by running the game in an emulator and using saved states to save after a Treasure Sphere <sup>(apparently one of their official names)</sup> appears, then reloading the saved state to break the orb when it is a different color. The contents will be the same every time.